# FTP example: Randomly not working

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I'm running this FTP example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp

And I'm getting some random issues:

- If I do a clean install, I'll get a Build sucess
- If I try to run the junit test individualy I'm getting sucess/failure randomly.

This is the failure trace that randomly I'm getting:

```
> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException:` Failed to invoke
> handler; nested exception is
> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on
> session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
> to create FTPClient, failedMessage=GenericMessage
> [payload=target\toSend\a.txt, headers={timestamp=1489108163505,
> id=84218d92-8f62-13aa-587f-3cf1e9768a5b}] at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:70)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.handleMessage(Unknown Source) at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
> at
> com.ftp.samples.FtpOutboundChannelAdapterSample.runDemo(FtpOutboundChannelAdapterSample.java:56)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
> Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to
> execute on session; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient at
> org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:444)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:283)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:273)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:265)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:170)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice$2.doWithRetry(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:201)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:89)
> ... 35 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to
> create FTPClient at
> org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:169)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:41)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:433)
> ... 52 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
> connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
> at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) at
> java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at
> org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:188) at
> org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:209) at
> org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.createClient(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:192)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:166)
> ... 54 more
```

I'm wondering if the reason could be related to the port that the session factory is using and the port that the server is using.

Answer (score 0):

They are not designed to be run individually; the `TestSuite` sets up a test `FtpServer` for use by the individual tests. See `TestSuite.setupFtpServer()`.

Comment: That's fine. I had modified the code and I have been using just the FtpOutboundChannelAdapterSample with @Suite.SuiteClasses. So basically I'm not testing neither FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample nor FtpOutboundGatewaySample. The point is why the test passes, and randomly it fails.

Comment: There's probably a race condition; try adding `Thread.sleep(2000)` after `server.start()`.

Comment: Didn't work. I got the same error. I'm still trying to figure out what's happening.